# selenium webdriver : unable to get data from webElement.getText()

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I ma using selenium for automation testing

I use to following code to verifying that a name is present in a search list

```
searchList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(searchListLocator));

logger.log("Size of list : " + searchList.size());
for (WebElement searchItem : searchList) 
{

    logger.log("Search Item name :" + searchItem.getText())
    if (searchItem.getText().trim().compareTo(name) == 0)
    {
        inResult = true;
        logger.log("Exact match found in the list");
        break;
    }
}
```

sometime i got the `Size of list : 11` but `searchItem.getText()` was an empty String

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing your HTML code...

Comment: I second Laurent's opinion. we need to see html code to help. sometimes, the value you are expecting may be present in the `value` tag, for such scenarios, `getText()` fetches blank value only.

Comment: there are ul an li elements in HTML code

Comment: Sometimes you may have to use getAttribute() Method instead getText()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- WebElements can sometimes be empty e.g. `'<br/>'`
- May contain only other elements e.g. `'<a hre='...'><img .../></a>'`.
- Also `getText()` only returns text that is **visible**.

Comment: With Java I was having this issue with the BR tag returning empty. Instead of `.getText()` I used `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` which will then return what I was looking for, including any HTML that is invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Try to not use `getText`, but to use `findElement` with xpath expression, like `"//li[contains(., 'your_name_expected_to_be_in_searchlist')]"`.

Therefore your loop will iterate through expected names and will try to find them in the searchList as elements, described with xpath's `contains` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Little modification in your code-

for (WebElement searchItem : searchList) 
{

    logger.log("Search Item name :" + searchItem.getText())
   for(int i=0;i<searchItem.size();i++)
{
if(searchItem.get(i).getText().equals(name)))
 inResult = true;
        logger.log("Exact match found in the list");
        break;
}
}
```